# Adding product to cart from CMS only submits one product from selection

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am using a CMS page to show one main product and a selection of accessories. The problem I have is that when I add a product to cart from the accessories section it doen't get added. Instead the main product gets added to the cart.

I have managed to isolate the problem down to the add to form for the main product:

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<div class="pull-right">
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?> class="form">
 <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->__('Price:'); ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice());; ?></h2>
         <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <p class="product-name"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity:'); ?></p>      
   <select name="qty" class="span1">
  <?php $i = 1 ?>
  <?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
      <?php echo $i?>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getMaxSaleQty()) ?>
</select>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?> 
</form></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Here is the code for the accessories -  the submit form is identical to above:

```
<?php 
$category_id = "49"; // category_id for "Accessories"
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description'), 'inner')
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id));
?>
<?php if($_productCollection->count()): ?>

       <?php 
       $products = array();
       foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) { 
        ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?> class="form">
    <div class="media">
          <a class="fancybox static-thumbs pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(500, 450); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
            <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150, 125); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
          </a>
    <div class="media-body span6">
       <h4 class="media-heading"><a class="view-item-button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Order'); ?> <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?><?php echo $this->__('&#8482;'); ?></a></h4>

        <p>
            <?php echo $_product->_data['short_description']; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="media pull-right"> 
        <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->__('Price:'); ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()); ?></h2><?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

  <p class="product-name"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity:'); ?></p>
   <select name="qty" class="span1">
  <?php $i = 1 ?>
  <?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
      <?php echo $i?>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getMaxSaleQty()) ?>
</select>

            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <?php } ?>

    </div></form>

<?php endif; ?>
<hr />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

If I remove the form the main product add to cart form the accessories are added successfully. I am not sure how to debug this and could do with some advice please!?!?

Comment: I think I need to specify a product_id for the main product...

Comment: If I remove the form from the main product i can add to cart but only one at a time even if more that one product is selected!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Had to resort to using an order now button that takes the customer to the product view page instead. It's means they can also configure the product on that page too!